# Caesar Shift Cipher, input exception error

Tags: java, encryption, input

I was having some issues with this originally, but found some different help on here. now I seem to be having an issue with an input exception error. I believe I have the correct formatting for the input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CaesarShift
{
//initialize private string for the alphabet
private final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
//public encryption code
public String encryptionMethod(String normText, int caesarShift)
{
    normText = normText.toLowerCase();
    String cipherText = "";
    for (int a = 0; a < normText.length(); a++)
    {
        int charP = ALPHABET.indexOf(normText.charAt(a));
        int shiftValue = (caesarShift + charP) % 26;
        char replaceValue = this.ALPHABET.charAt(shiftValue);
        cipherText += replaceValue;
    }
    return cipherText;
}
public String decryptionMethod(String cipherText,int caesarShift)
{
    cipherText = cipherText.toLowerCase();
    String normText = "";
    for (int a = 0; a < cipherText.length(); a++)
    {
        int charP = this.ALPHABET.indexOf(cipherText.charAt(a));
        int keyValue = (charP - caesarShift) % 26;
        if(keyValue < 0)
        {
            keyValue = this.ALPHABET.length() + keyValue;
       }
       char replaceValue = this.ALPHABET.charAt(keyValue);
       normText += replaceValue;
    }
    return normText;
}
```

}

Then I have the tester method it where i am having the actual issue of the input exception error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CaesarShiftTester
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //import of the scanner method to ask the user for the input they would like
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the text you would like to do something with?");
    String normText = in.next();
    System.out.println("What is the Caesar Shift Value?");
    int caesarShift = in.nextInt();
    //new declaration of the CaesarShift class to report back to easily
    CaesarShift shift = new CaesarShift();
    //decalre the need properties for the encryption
    String cipherText = shift.encryptionMethod(normText, caesarShift);
    System.out.println("Your normal text is: " + normText);
    System.out.println("Your text after encryption is: " + cipherText);
    String cnormText = shift.decryptionMethod(cipherText, caesarShift);
    System.out.println("Your encrypted text is: " + cipherText);
    System.out.println("Your decrypte text is: " + cnormText);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the somewhat messy code, I typically do clean up when a program is done and working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a good idea to clean up the code before you post a question, ideally reducing it to a [mcve]. At the moment, we know there's an "input exception error", but not where, or what the message is, etc. I'd strongly urge you to reduce the code to a minimal example, include the error in the question too, and what you've tried in order to diagnose it. You may well find that in the process of doing that, you solve the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program should work OK if you input only 1 word. If you include spaces, exception appears. The problem is on line

```
String normText = in.next();
```

It should be

```
String normText = in.nextLine();
```

to get the whole line as input `text`. `next()` doesn't work as you expected because

> A `Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches **whitespace**.

So it matched only the first word and tried to parse the next word as an `int` (because of your next line `int caesarShift = in.nextInt();`)

Some other points:

- in your encryption/decryption methods, you should check if the input `char` is a letter (e.g. using `Character.isLetter()`) and shift only those chars (currently, it won't find space in `ALPHABET` so `indexOf` returns `-1`)
- using `StringBuilder` when concatenating Strings in a loop, it's faster

Comment: Thanks! The in.nextLine worked out perfectly